# how to make another image of this tag (by dragging) which does not effect the original one

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you run this code there will be a box "Drag me Down", I need to drag it down to make another copy (each time I drag it) of same box without effecting the original box.
What changes should I make in my code to get the desired result as described above.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: "true",
      helper:"clone"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).draggable({
      //connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "valid"
      //var dra = jQuery.extend({}, draggable)
    });
    //$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li id="sortable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.clone()` function to achieve what you want.

Changed code

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: "true",
      helper:"clone"
    });
    $( "#sortable" ).draggable({
      //connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "valid",
        stop:function(){
            $(this).clone().appendTo("body");
        }  
      //var dra = jQuery.extend({}, draggable)
    });
    //$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/az9uxnr9/7/)